# Visual Studio add-in API resources

Tags: visual-studio-2008, api, visual-studio-addins

Where can I find examples and API information, besides the MSDN, on creating add-ins for Visual Studio .net 2008?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Download the [Visual Studio SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=30402623-93ca-479a-867c-04dc45164f5b&DisplayLang=en).
2. Go to the [Visual Studio Extensibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsx/default.aspx) Developer Center
3. Visit the [Visual Studio Extensibility Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/threads)

Answer (score 2):

[Creating Visual Studio Add-Ins](http://www.code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?quickid=0710082)

Answer (score 2):

Book: [Visual Studio Extensibility](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-Visual-Studio-Extensibility.productCd-0470230843.html) (Wrox)

[image: Visual Studio Extensibility]