# There's space for a better Visual Studio QuickWatch window. Is there a way to make your own?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, envdte

I think there's room for improvements in QuickWatch window. There could be a way to implement special viewers for certain types. For instance:,

- EntityFramework's `ObjectQueries` could display the generated SQL.
- `IEnumerables` could optionally display the list of elements in an inspectable manner.
- `Bitmap` could display the bitmap.
- `GraphicsPath` could draw the path.

Is it too hard to achieve? I've searched the `DTE` API and I didn't find a way to access the memory of the running/debugging program.

Comment: You can create your own [Debug Visualizers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zayyhzts.aspx?ppud=4) that are used inside Quick Watch.

Comment: You wouldn't want to use DTE for this.  You'd want to find the particular [extension point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885122.aspx) for the quick watch window and then create a replacement.  That's how, for example, the [References dialog was replaced back in 2010.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/06/22/what-s-next-for-the-productivity-power-tools.aspx)  Not sure if the PPT extension code is open source or not, but you could probably reflect it and get some hints as to the overall pattern.

Comment: The existence of third-party plug-ins for VS like Whole Tomato's Visual Assist suggests that there is a way to do generic plug-ins for VS, above and beyond debug visualizers.  I imagine such a plug-in API would have access to all the same stuff that the built-in macro system can see, which should include debugger state.  So this should be doable.  I can't comment on difficulty however, I've never done it.  This page looks like a promising place to start, though: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb286983.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There is always room for add in's for Visual Studio. As a developer I always like the "if its not a feature, add it" philosophy. I have never done it but it looks like [this will be a good place to start for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718770/visual-studio-add-in-api-resources):